# Name of old cartoon with a mecha suit. Villain is revealed to be the protagonist's father and siblings

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I was born in 1994 and I live in Italy. As a child I used to watch a cartoon/anime based on a guy Who could summon a mecha armor with the help of a crystal. The crystal then gets broken and he needs to use a fake suit to summon the Mecha armor.

Final boss is his father (all the enemies in the series are his siblings infected with some mind controlling virus).

Answer (score 11):

This is almost certainly [Tekkaman Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekkaman_Blade) from 1992, released in the English-speaking world as "Teknoman". Some of the key points:

- The main character, D-Boy / Nick Carter transforms into the titular Blade using a green crystal.
- About half-way through the series, his crystal is damaged, and it is installed in a robot named Pegas to help him transform.
- The process that made him a Tekkaman was also meant to brainwash him to be on the side of the villains, but his father (who was rejected from the conversion process) released him part-way.
- The main enemies in the series are revealed to be his siblings, who went through the full conversion process.
- The final enemy is not his father, but his eldest brother.