# Name of Anime featuring power crystals

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember this anime that use some kind of power crystal all of them have different crystal but the main protagonist have the red crystal and all the crystal can transform into some kind of beast but it was small but the true power of this Crystal is its transform and it will turn into some kind of armor for the holder.

I remember the one episode that the crystal of the main character broke because when he use the armor while fighting the armor got damage and when the armor goes back to its original crystal form it has a crack on it so it need to fix and he cant fight.

I'm pretty sure its not power stone cause when they transform the armor is not full body the only reveal in the armor is the faces.

Comment: So, not [Power Stone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WB_ZU1T57JQ)?

Comment: No its not i know that its look similar but its not power stone

Comment: Just to clarify, since the Power Stone opening shows him both with his face revealed, and with it covered with his armor, in your anime, everything is covered but the face?

Comment: Question would be improved with basic punctuation.

Comment: Could it have been Tekkaman Blade (aka Teknoman), as described in these posts? [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175544/35146) [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/268834/35146)

Comment: Additional for this information is the power gem can transform into some kind of small beast like the bakugan when they are in the ball form

Comment: @ConMan the part about the gem shattering looks indeed like Tekkaman Blade, but some other details do not match. Blade crystal is blue, not red and the armor covers the face. Still, the OP could be misremembering things